# Hadoop reduce task stuck at 0%

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm following some guide to set up the pseudo distributed mode, I ran start-all.sh and the daemons are all good (6 of them), then I launch my WordCount example which runs well in standalone mode, but stuck at map 100%, reduce 0%.

Looking at the jobtracker, the reduce task is at status `reduce > copy`.
The only error log locates in `secondarynamenode.log`:

```
2013-02-27 23:29:59,555 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:my_user_name cause:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused 
2013-02-27 23:29:59,555 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode: Exception in doCheckpoint:  
2013-02-27 23:29:59,555 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

I can ssh localhost without password. Hadoop version is 1.1.1. I launch a jar file from commande line.

Really no idea what's wrong, some help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you have replaced the real username with `my_user_name`. Please use `jps` in command line to list hadoop's daemons. Are they all really running (especially `NameNode`)? Furthermore - have you configured `dfs.namenode.secondary.http` in `hdfs-site.xml` correctly?

Comment: I'm sure that all daemons are ok and the job has run through map but stuck before reduce task. However I didn't set dfs.namenode.secondary.http, what should its value be?

Comment: The default values are listed [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml). If 0.0.0.0 is not working, try a real IP.

Answer (score 0):

How much data are you running the word count on? If you are running on a large data set in standalone mode without using a combiner, then it's going to cause some trouble. Try

```
job.setMapperClass(<Mapper_Class>);
job.setCombinerClass(<Reducer_Class>);
job.setReducerClass(<Reducer_Class>);
```

in the main method containing the driver in your program. This might help you out.